# Android: onActivityResult is not called

Tags: android

I have an activity whose view contains a ListView and I have used an adapter to show the items in the ListView.

**ReceptionistListToEditActivity.java**:

```
private ReceptionistListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receptionist_list_to_edit);
    ArrayList<ReceptionistViewModel> receptionists = getAllReceptionists();
    adapter = new ReceptionistListAdapter(ReceptionistListToEdit.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, receptionists);
    ListView receptionistListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ReceptionistList);
    receptionistListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

From the adapter I am opening a popup on the click of an edit button which is present on each item of the ListView.

**ReceptionistListAdapter.java:**

```
public static int RECEPTIONIST_SAVED = 1;

private void openEditReceptionistPopup(long receptionistId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditReceptionistPopup.class);
    new DataLoadingProgressDialog(context).showDialog();
    intent.putExtra("ReceptionistId", receptionistId);
    ((ReceptionistListToEditActivity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, RECEPTIONIST_SAVED);
}
```

On closing of the popup, I want to send back some data in the intent, which I want in the adapter.

**EditReceptionistPopup.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(someData);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

But, the onActivityResult method in the activity class, is never called.

**ReceptionistListToEditActivity.java**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == adapter.RECEPTIONIST_SAVED) {
        ReceptionistViewModel viewModel = (ReceptionistViewModel) data.getSerializableExtra("receptionistDetails");
        adapter.onActivityResult(viewModel);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have not added launchMode `singleTask` under manifest to the activity where you have implement `onActivityResult()`

Edited:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: No, I haven't. Here is the manifest entry:

`<activity
            android:name=".ReceptionistListToEditActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomDialogTheme"
            >
        </activity>`

Comment: Thanks, but still the same result after making the change.

Answer (score -1):

> **Replace your openEditReceptionistPopup with below and give a try**

- Make context public in your activity
- Call startActivityForResult with the public context

  ```
      public static int RECEPTIONIST_SAVED = 1;       
      private void openEditReceptionistPopup(long receptionistId) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditReceptionistPopup.class);
          new DataLoadingProgressDialog(context).showDialog();
          intent.putExtra("ReceptionistId", receptionistId);
          context.startActivityForResult(intent, RECEPTIONIST_SAVED);
      }
  ```

Comment: `startActivityForResult` method is not available in the adapter.